# Get all dates that have a value in a particular month in Laravel Carbon?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-8

How can I get all dates that have value in a particular month in Laravel carbon? I tried `groupBy`, but it was grouped by months, and I can't fetch the date from a particular month. Below is the sample code. I only fetch the month value, not the dates. My expectation is I want to fetch all dates in a particular month

```php
$fetch_data = Calendar::groupBy('month')->get();
$get_data = array();

foreach ($fetch_data as $holiday => $key) {
    $data_events = array(
        'id' => $key->id,
        'title' => ucwords($key->holiday_title),
        'start' => $key->holiday_date
    );

    array_push($get_data, $data_events);
}

return response()->json($get_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `groupBy`, you might simply add a `where` clause:

```
Calendar::where('month', $month)->get();
```